# Asterisk Cannot record call after fetching it from parking lot

Tags: asterisk

I'm using asterisk/freepbx. Asterisk is not recording calls that are fetched from park. Here is my call flow.

A calls to Asterisk Server(AS)
Call is picked up by extension B
B does an attended transfer by dialling *2200 (200 is my default parking lot)
C dials 1 to fetch the parked call
C dials *1 to record the call.

Recording is not done.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix and it works for me. In the asterisk log i found that asterisk tries to record to an invalid file with no filename, just an extension(.wav). It executed 2  files - /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/parkfetch.agi and /var/lib/asterisk/bin/one_touch_record.php.

one_touch_record.php generates filename from data read from channel, like year, date, mixmonitor folder etc, but as there was no valid filename in the log, these should be null here.

```
$mixMonDir = getVariable($channel, "MIXMON_DIR");
$year = getVariable($channel, "YEAR");
$month = getVariable($channel, "MONTH");
$day = getVariable($channel, "DAY");
$mixMonFormat = getVariable($channel, "MIXMON_FORMAT");
$mixMonPost = getVariable($channel, "MIXMON_POST");
$astman->mixmonitor($channel, "{$mixMonDir}{$year}/{$month}/{$day}/{$callFileName}.{$mixMonFormat}", "a", $mixMonPost, rand());
```

So i inspected the parkfetch.agi  were i found that these channel vars are copied only if REC_STATUS is "RECORDING" and in this case REC_STATUS is "INITIALIZED". So i added an OR clause ie i changed  if ($rec_status == "RECORDING") to  if ($rec_status == "RECORDING" || $rec_status=="INITIALIZED")

```
if ($channel) {
        $rec_status = get_var("IMPORT($channel,REC_STATUS)");

        $agi->set_variable('REC_STATUS', $rec_status);
        if ($rec_status == "RECORDING" || $rec_status=="INITIALIZED") {
                foreach (array('MIXMON_DIR', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'CALLFILENAME', 'MIXMON_FORMAT', 'MIXMON_POST', 'MON_FMT') as $v) {
                        $agi->set_variable($v, get_var("IMPORT($channel,$v)"));
                }
        }
}
```

And it worked. Now when I pressed *1 after fetching call from park, it is getting recorded.

If someone found a better solution, please leave it as a comment in my blog.
http://sachindotg.blogspot.in/2014/02/asterisk-cannot-record-call-after.html